# Two methods which one will be chosen

Tags: java, inheritance, overloading

I have two java classes.

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
```

I have class that accepts these classes, but requires different implementation methods.

```
class Holder {
     public void accept(A a) {} // choice 1
     public void accept(B b) {} //choice 2
}
```

If I supply a holder with a B object, which method will it choose?

Looking at the code I'd go with choice 2, but choice 1 can also accept due to the inheritance.

So who can tell me the runtime logic of this?

Comment: If you pass an object of type `B` it will choose the later of your methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In all cases, the *most specific* method is invoked.

If the *type* of the object being passed is `B`, then the `B` method will be invoked, but if a `B` instance is assigned to a variable of type `A`, the `A` method will be invoked:

```
A obj = new B();
accept(obj);  // will invoke the A method
```

The runtime type of the object is not used to bind to the method, because Java is a *statically typed* language, method binding is done a *compile* time.

Comment: Hmmh,  im kinda sad now couse i thought this might be the cause of a bug im facing heh

Comment: @MichaelDibbets there might still be undecidable situations, when your class extends two interfaces and the methods in question accept these.

Comment: @Michael check the recent edit. Is the instance of B being passed via a variable of type A?

Comment: It shouldn't but i might have missed a spot where it could be a A at some point. Does that change things?

Comment: Yes, that could be the problem. Use your IDE to find all places where the method is called from and check the type of the *variable* being passed (not the type of the *object*)

Comment: Oh joy, that means 200 places to check. One place checked, pass it around, 199 places to check. Thanks :-) at least I know Java will choose the most specific accepting java method.